# RealmSwift: No such module 'RealmSwift'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I configured RealmSwift 1.0.0 Latest Using Docs into the Xcode project. After installation i created a class file and getting module error - like: No such module 'RealmSwift' in class file.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.
[image]

4.
[image]

5. After adding the Realm Plugin, i created a class and get the module error below.

[image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you've added the path to `RealmSwift.framework` to your framework search paths. The [Realm Swift installation instructions](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-22) say to add the *parent path* of `RealmSwift.framework` (i.e., the containing directory) to your framework search paths.

Answer (score 24):

A very important sanity check: if you run into this and you're using Cocoapods, please make sure you **open the .xcworkspace** and not the .xcodeproj file!

Answer (score 14):

Follow below steps, it may be useful for you.

- Go To: Product > Schemes > New Scheme...
- Select: RealmSwift and click OK
- Build the RealmSwift target (cmd + b)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem like you.
I resolved it by add the following code into pod file.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with only the archive build, it turns out that I had specified in my Podfile a higher platform version than the app's target. So bottom line: make sure that your app's target platform matches the one in the Podfile

Comment: Thank you very much. The target platform and the one in the Podfile much be the attention point.

Comment: very important write `platform :ios, '10.0'`,  target must be **10.0**

Answer (score 3):

Follow below instructions:

1. Clean from Xcode (**Shift+Cmd+K**)
2. Delete the Derived Data directory (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
3. Build the project  (**Cmd+B**)

Answer (score 1):

After "pod install" or "pod update" fix it

else

try this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean    
pod deintegrate    
pod cache clean --all      
rm Podfile    
pod "deinitialize" to fix that issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this problem as well for 2 hours; I tried several things, like cleaning, uninstalling and reinstalling the Realm pod, changing the Podfile, and so on.

Nothing worked until I restarted the computer.

I use Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9.2 Beta, Swift 3, High Sierra MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

After "pod install" restart Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can add Run script file for your project.

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Realm Database/Pods-Realm Database-frameworks.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you how I get that error and how I solved it.

I am using Carthage in my project, but I am new team member, so I did `git clone` the project. But I opened the project before run cathage upload command. Although I ran the cathage command, I got that error.
I could fix it doing the next:

- Go to the project file.
- In build phaces -> run script -> Input file.
- Add `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework` and
  `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework`

I do not know why it is not always automatically linked.

Answer (score 0):

For me there first was an error like 'could not build Objective-C module 'RealmSwift'' which I could fix by deleting the Derived Data Folder, Pods Folder, Podfile.lock and the .xcworkspace and after that there was the error saying 'No such module 'RealmSwift'' which only disappeared when I first tried to build the project. Now everything works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i tried other suggested solutions and it didn't work for me but this  replacement fixed problem and the error have gone

Try use

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

instead

```
pod 'Realm', '~> 10.1'
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, setting project format to current Xcode version in pod target helped:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqozI.png]